# Что за формат времени у СМС, выглядит как "21/08/27,10:56:09+22"?

Tags: python, время, смс

```
"21/08/27,10:56:09+22"
```

не могу понять что за +22, бывает тут +18,
это дата смс сообщения. Я эту дату получаю из СМС модуля, m590
Полная дата с кодом номера выглядит примерно так

```
REC READ,+7909019xxxx,,"21/08/27,10:56:09+22"
```

как правильно должен выглядеть шаблон для парсинга даты этой?

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("21/08/27,10:56:09+22", '%y/%m/%d,%H:%M:%S+18????').isoformat();
```

Comment: *не могу понять что за +22* Сильно похоже на смещение зоны времени... чисто по формату и местоположению... но тоже какое-то нестандартное. Может, это зона GMT-02:00?

Comment: `это дата смс сообщения` это вопрос или утверждение? :) Числа после +22 может быть чем угодно: миллисекундам, часовым поясом, температурой за бортом (:D)

Comment: Это утверждение. я эту дату получаю с смс модуля. Добавил строку с номером телефона

Comment: методом тыка. отправив сообщение получил +18 а время совпадает с моим московским. значит если +22 это + 4 часа к московскому?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Беглый гуглёж говорит, что это это часовой пояс SMS-центра в единицах «четверть часа» https://www.developershome.com/sms/cmglCommand.asp

Т.е. `+22` = `22/4` = `5.5` = `+05:30` в нормальном написании.

Что наводит на мысль что SMS-центр находится в Индии (или просто криво настроен).

UPD: [GSM_03.40 Time_Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.40#Time_Format)

Comment: только если мои +18 перевести получается +4.5 ч а у меня +3 часа московское время.  Вопрос. это что за зона получается? сервера сообщений? не моя местная

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг подозреваю что банально криворукие админы

Comment: Либо SMSC в Афганистане или Иране, но это вряд ли…